# Ractive two-way databinding with expressions

Tags: javascript, data-binding, ractivejs, 2-way-object-databinding, javascript-databinding

I'd like to have an `input` represent a list of primitive (string, number) values so you can enter them as comma-separated values but update the model as an array:

```
"Transforms": [
        {
            "Fn": "TheFunctionName",
            "Args": [ "arg1", 2, "arg3" ]
        },
        {
            "Fn": "AnotherMethod",
            "Args": [ 4.678 ]
        },
    ]
```

Would be administered with:

```
{{#each Transforms:i}}
   <li>
       <input value="{{Fn}}" placeholder="Function Name" />
       <input value="{{implode(Args)}}" placeholder="Function Arguments" />
   </li>
{{/each}}
```

and would render something like:

`* [ TheFunctionName ] [ "arg1", 2, "arg3" ]
* [ AnotherMethod   ] [ 4.678 ]`

Mainly so that I don't need to figure out a good UI to dynamically add/remove argument inputs (like bind on certain keypress, use buttons to add/remove fields, etc).

I could use a "placeholder" property for databinding, and probably observe that to update the actual property, but then I'd need to filter it out when 'serializing' the underlying model.  It seems like I could use [computed properties](http://docs.ractivejs.org/0.5/computed-properties), which have a getter and a setter, but it's not clear from the docs how it works with nested properties in a list (i.e. there are many entries in `data` with the `Transforms` list).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The trick here is to not use two-way binding, but to use more traditional event handling techniques. This example listens for `change` events on the second input (not `input` events, which happen with each keystroke, since that would cause the cursor to jump about while the user is still typing) in each `<li>`, and tries to evaluate its contents. Meanwhile, a formatter takes the arguments and turns them back into a string:

```js
var ractive = new Ractive({
    el: 'main',
    template: '#template',
    data: {
        transforms: [
            {
                fn: 'TheFunctionName',
                args: [ 'arg1', 2, 'arg3' ]
            },
            {
                fn: 'AnotherMethod',
                args: [ 4.678 ]
            }
        ],
        format: function ( args ) {
            return args.map( JSON.stringify ).join( ', ' );
        }    
    },
    updateArgs: function ( index, str ) {
        var keypath = 'transforms[' + index + '].args',
            args = this.get( keypath );
        
        try {
            // or use JSON.parse, if you don't want to eval
            this.set( keypath, eval( '([' + str + '])' ) );
        } catch ( err ) {
            // reset
            this.set( keypath, null );
            this.set( keypath, args );
        }
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="http://cdn.ractivejs.org/edge/ractive.js"></script>

<main></main>

<script id='template' type='text/ractive'>
    <h2>input</h2>
    <ul>
        {{#each transforms:i}}
            <li>
                <input value='{{fn}}' placeholder='function name'/>
                <input
                    twoway='false'
                    value='{{format(args)}}'
                    placeholder='function arguments'
                    on-change='updateArgs(i,event.node.value)'
                />
            </li>
        {{/each}}
    </ul>
    
    <h2>output</h2>
    <ul>
        {{#each transforms}}
            <li>
                <p>function name: <strong>{{fn}}</strong></p>
                <p>args:</p>
                <ul>
                    {{#each args}}
                        <p>{{JSON.stringify(this)}} ({{typeof this}})</p>
                    {{/each}}
                </ul>
            </li>
        {{/each}}
    </ul>
</script>
```

Comment: I had just about come to [the same conclusion](https://github.com/ractivejs/ractive/issues/689#issuecomment-67568203), but I wasn't sure of the right way to declare it.  I was also concerned by the console warning `Two-way binding does not work with expressions...` -- is this just a friendly reminder, and can be ignored?

Comment: Yes, it's just a debugging message, in case anyone tried to do `<input value='{{number*2}}'>` and was surprised that entering 10 didn't cause `number` to become 5. It won't cause any problems with your app, and the message (should?) be squelched in the next version if the element has `twoway='false'`.

Comment: ah...I think my problems stem from the fact that I'm using CDN "latest" rather than "edge" -- I was getting an error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'split' of undefined` on every keypress

Comment: So this may be a dumb question, but if you're passing `event` as an argument, why not reference the `event.context` directly for updates as opposed to get/set on keypath; or for that matter use `event.keypath` rather than reconstructing it?

Comment: I've managed to reproduced my latest issue -- [this](http://jsfiddle.net/drzaus/34aec2v9/2/) vs [that](http://jsfiddle.net/drzaus/34aec2v9/3/), where the second every so often throws `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'str' of undefined` and the next click dumps the "missing" rows